# Case statement without null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to compare YOY data and I am trying to use a case statement in order to split by year.
What I have been trying to do is that

```
(Case
When year(date) = 2010 Then 'sales year 2010'
When year(date) = 2011 Then 'sales year 2011'
Else 
End) as Year
```

but the above one isn't working cause I wanted to get each year data by column, not as rows under the same column.

So, next what I tried is that

```
(Case
When year(date) = 2010 Then sum(sales) End) as 'sales year 2010', 
(Case
When year(date) = 2011 Then sum(sales) End) as 'sales year 2011'
```

And I got the below.

| Item | Sales Year 2010 | Sales Year 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | null | 2,500 |
| A | 5,000 | null |
| B | null | 200 |
| B | 7,000 | null |
| C | null | 2,500 |
| C | 5,000 | null |
| D | null | 200 |
| D | 7,000 | null |

What I want to get is this.

| Item | Sales Year 2010 | Sales Year 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5,000 | 2,500 |
| B | 7,000 | 200 |
| C | 5,000 | 2,500 |
| D | 7,000 | 200 |

Could someone please advise how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: You need to some the complete query, because the second option should produce the right results, but it looks like your group by is causing additional rows.

Comment: Put the case expression INSIDE the sum aggregate.

Answer (score 5):

You want to sum the `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT
    Item,
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2010 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [Sales Year 2010],
    SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2011 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS [Sales Year 2011]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Item;
```

Comment: For the OPs reference, this is called **conditional aggregation**.